# pass large data to other app

Tags: android-intent, share

i want to pass huge data to another app.i have a code fore sharing data to another app with intent.but my problem is my code is working good for email.and when i share data to WhatsApp then its not good work.then my code pass only some lines.and some data cant pass.(i mean i have a 150 lines,but my code pass only 30-40 lines)and showing **"??"** symbol.how can i fix it.please suggest me.

this is my code

```
AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
            String product = collist_1.get(info.position);  
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
             sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");     
             String shareSub = "My Data";   
             sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, shareSub); 
             sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, product);  
             startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share using"));
```

and this is my error
[image]

thanks in advance